# Excel: Keep *first* calculated value in cell and ignore/delete formula afterwards?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

In column `A`, cell `A1` contains `1` as a static value. The value of `A2` is cacluated by `=A1+1`, etc.

If I would delete row `4`, the values in `A1:A3` would still remain the same, but the values in `A5:A8` (then `A4:A7`) would decrement by one.

So, my question now is: How can I prevent the numbers in `A5:A8` (then `A4:A7`) from decrementing so that the numbers would go as follows: `1`, `2`, `3`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`.

For that, it would be a good thing to modify formulas so that they are only evaluated *once* and then deleted or deactivated or something like that. **I know that this can be done *globally*, using a certain option, but I want to apply it to column `A` *only*.**

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to switch off recalculating selected area. There is a workaround - copy the A column and use paste as a values (check [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-cell-values-not-formulas-12687b4d-c79f-4137-b0cc-947c229c55b9) how to do it). Then the values in cell won't change anymore. Is this suitable for you?

Comment: Why not just use auto fill to produce your numbers and not a formula, that way they are static.

Comment: Tried all sorts of funny long formulas and circular reference tricks but I can't crack it using formula ;[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Ctrl+C cells and then use Ctrl+**Alt**+V and select `Values`.
This will paste calculated values on top of your formulas effectively deleting them.

Answer (score -2):

If your value 1 is in cell A1, write formula =row() in cell A2 and drag down.